# PHP concatanate variable name

Tags: php

In **Propriete** entity I have 5 field called image1 image2 image3 image4 image5

I wan't to add these fields in a for loop

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
  for($i=0;$i<count($this->request->data['files'])&&$i<5;$i++){
               //... some code
                    $propriete->{'image'.$i+1} = $file['name'];
                }
            }
```

Can someone help me?

**EDIT**

This is the code of my loop:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($this->request->data['files']) && $i<5; $i++){
    $file=$this->request->data['files'][$i];
    $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1); //get the extension
    $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'); //set allowed extensions
    if(in_array($ext, $arr_ext))
    {
        //do the actual uploading of the file. First arg is the tmp name, second arg is
        //where we are putting it
        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . '/img/' . $file['name']);
        debug($file['name']);
        //prepare the filename for database entry
        $propriete->{'image'.$i+1} = $file['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: `$file['name']` makes no sense, please show enough code to explain where this variable comes from

Comment: @RiggsFolly check the edit

Comment: Can you specify in which line the error is seen? Is it  $propriete->{'image'.$i+1} = $file['name']; Are you not getting the filename?Or cannot set the filename in the object property

Comment: So what is the actual problem _but it doesn't work_ is not much help to us

Comment: The problem is $prorpete->image1 return null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work fine, you're just missing parenthesis which makes your concatenation go haywire

```
$propriete->{'image'.($i+1)}="test";
```

This can also be demonstrated by this simple test

```
$i=2;
echo 'image'.$i+1;  // 1 :)
```

VS

```
echo 'image'.($i+1);  //image3
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the value of every method in a variable to store the value and then use it.For eg

```
$values = $this->request->data['files'];
```

You cannot for loop the data without putting them in a variable first.

If you cannot find the filename the problem should be that you are naming the object property in the wrong manner.You should enclose $i+1 with quotes.

Comment: I did that i stor the data from the request in $file

Comment: This isn't the right solution but it isn't me who have downvote i don't have the score yet..